# Selection with join and sum from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, algorithm

```
Id       Item
--------------
1        ItemA 
2        ItemB
3        ItemC

itemid     Price
----------------
1          4
1          3
1          9
2          2
2          4
2          3
```

How I can select with sum from 2 tables? Like as:

```
ItemA 16
ItemB 9
ItemC 0
```

Comment: Is there any kind of referential keys between the tables, like primary key/ foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the table using a `LEFT JOIN` and apply an aggregate function `SUM()` to the `price` field:

```
select t1.item, IsNull(sum(t2.price), 0) total
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.itemid
group by t1.item
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8425/3)

The `LEFT JOIN` will allow for the records not in the second table to be included in the final result.  I added the `IsNull()` to the `sum()` to replace any `null` values with a zero.

Result:

```
|  ITEM | TOTAL |
-----------------
| ItemA |    16 |
| ItemB |     9 |
| ItemC |     0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select a.Item, ISNULL(SUM(b.Price), 0) AS TOTALSum
from Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b on a.Id=b.ItemId
Group by a.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select item,sum(price) from table1 left outer join table2 
 on table1.id=table2.itemid
 group by item
```