# linq query to take aggregate and normal column in c# mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables `fooditem(itemid,itemname,itemprice)` and another `rating(itemid,vote,itemid,username)`

How to get sum of votes groupby itemid in rating table and the itemname ,itemprice corresponding to the total rating on each food item.
sql query is

```
select table2.sum(votes),table1.itemname,table1.itemprice from table1,table2 where table1.itemid==table2.itemid group by table2.itemid
```

I started with this query.Bad luck!

```
    List<FoodView> items= (from a in db.FoodItems 
                                   join b in db.Ratings on a.itemid equals b.itemid
                                   group b by  b.itemid into g

                                   select new FoodView
                                   {
                                    itemname=g.Select(d=>d.itemname),
                                    itemprice=g.Select(d=>d.itemprice),
                                    vote=g.Sum(d=>d.vote)
                                   }).ToList();
```

FoodViewModel vm = new FoodViewModel { Foodviews= items};

**My Model is**

```
  public class FoodViewModel
{
    public List<FoodView> Foodviews { get; set; }

    public FoodViewModel()
    {
        Foodviews = new List<FoodView>();
    }
}

public class FoodView
{
    public long? itemid { get; set; }
    public string itemname { get; set; }

    public long? itemprice { get; set; }

    public long? vote { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: can any one help??the linq query of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471974/selection-with-join-and-sum-from-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please use following query:


 var foodViewsList = (from t in fooditems
                         join r in ratings on t.itemid equals r.itemid
                         group r by new { r.itemid, t.itemname, t.itemprice } into g
                         select new FoodView
                         {
                             itemid = g.Key.itemid,
                             itemname = g.Key.itemname,
                             itemprice = g.Key.itemprice,
                             vote = g.Sum(x => x.vote)
                         }).ToList();
```