# LINQ version of SQL with left join and group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can any one tell me the linq query for this sql?

```
select 
  t1.item, 
  IsNull(sum(t2.price), 0) total
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.itemid
group by t1.item
```

Comment: This  query marked as a solution, what kind of error do you get? Provide more information.

Comment: i tried like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719846/linq-query-to-take-aggregate-and-normal-column-in-c-sharp-mvc

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as

```
var result = (from t1 in table1 
                      join t2 in table2 on t1.id equals t2.itemId
                     into t2d from td in t2d.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     group t1 by t1.item into t1g select new {item=t1g.key, sum =t1g.Sum(p=>p.price??0)} ).ToList();
```

Comment: how to multiply with that sum?

Comment: What do you want to multiply?

Comment: Are you talking about this..   sum =5*t1g.Sum(p=>p.price??0)

Comment: with the count of rows

Comment: for example how to divide aggregate sum with aggregate count??

Comment: sum =t1g.Count()*t1g.Sum(p=>p.price??0)

Comment: sir please help me (g.Sum(x => (int?)x.vote) ?? 0)/g.Count() getting error

Answer (score 0):

LINQ version of your SQL query,

```
var resutl = from t1 in objtable1
                     join t2 in objtable2 on t1.id equals t2.itemid into j1
                     from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     group j2 by t1.item into grouped
                     select new { item = grouped.Key,  sum =  grouped.Sum(t => t != null ? (t.price ??0 ) : 0) };
```

If you have value (id) in table1 but not in table2 (itemid) then `t` inside `grouped.Sum()` will be null so you need to check if `t` is not null and `t.price` also is not null inside `grouped.sum()`

Comment: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: here g.count() must be grater than 0 otherwise it will throws an error.

Comment: can you share inner exception.

Comment: it is because of zero

Comment: but i have data.and i am getting sum

Comment: how can i give condition that divide only if greater than 0

Comment: I think error is not due to count() is zero but may be other reason.. can you check inner exception and share it.